# Volley.newRequestQueue() not working

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I am trying to create an Android-based news app. This news app requests for a JSON object that has an array of JSON objects, each object representing a news article. I am using Volley library for performing these requests.

I created a ContextHelper class to statically obtain Application Context for various uses in this way:-

```
public class ContextHelper {
public static Context ctxForAll;

public static void setCtxForAll(Context context){
    ctxForAll=context;
}}
```

Then I called the constructor from MainActivity like`
 ContextHelper.setCtxForAll(getApplicationContext());

Now I passed this context in the Volley.newRequestQueue()method.
public class NWReqUtility {

```
private static String TAG = NWReqUtility.class.getName();

private static NWReqUtility ourInstance;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private static Context mContext;

public static synchronized NWReqUtility getInstance() {
    if (ourInstance==null){
        ourInstance = new NWReqUtility();
    }
    return ourInstance;
}

private NWReqUtility() {
    mContext = ContextHelper.ctxForAll;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue==null){
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}
public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req){
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancel(){
    mRequestQueue.cancelAll(TAG);
}}
```

But when I run the app, I found out that the Request was not successful.
On further going through the code, I found that the line

```
Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
```

is giving the problem.

Why is this issue occurring? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is the error? post your logcat output

Comment: Use getApplicationContext() instead of context and its done

Answer (score 1):

Inplace of your contexthelper use this class and add this to the AndroidManifest
as follows:

```
    <application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
```

And the class:

```
public class MyApp extends Application{
    private static MyApp instance = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }

    public static MyApp getsInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

     @Override
     protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
         super.attachBaseContext(base);
     }

     public static Context getAppContext(){
         return instance.getApplicationContext();
     }
}
```

And then in your code:

```
 public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
     if (mRequestQueue==null){
         mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MyApp.getAppContext());
     }
     return mRequestQueue;
}
```